# Binding Property to Two Different Controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, visibility, contentcontrol

I have a WPF form with a `content control` and a `custom control`. The `content control` swaps in views based on a radio button selection.  Once the user takes an action on the view, I set the nocustomer on the parent `viewmodel` (the WPF form containing the two controls) to false.  When this occurs, the visibility of `content control` correctly disappears.  Unfortunately, the visibility of the `custom control` remains unchanged (it should have also disappeared). I'm actually perplexed because in my mind they have the exact same implementation and therefore should behave the same.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ViewSwap" Content="{Binding SearchingViewModel}" 
Visibility="{Binding NoCustomer, Converter={StaticResource 
BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SearchOptions, Path=IsSelected}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AddressTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>

<views:CTACallSubmit x:Name="CallSubmit" 
Visibility="{Binding NoCustomer, Converter={StaticResource 
BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Update:

MainWindow's `DataContext`

```
public partial class CTALight : Window
{
    public CTALight()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = CTALightViewModel.GetInstance();
    }
}
```

MainViewModel

```
 public class CTALightViewModel : ObservableObject
 {
    public static CTALightViewModel _mainViewModel;

    public static CTALightViewModel GetInstance()
    {
        if (_mainViewModel == null)
            _mainViewModel = new CTALightViewModel();          

        return _mainViewModel;
    }

    private CTALightViewModel()
    {
    }
```

}

CTACallSubmit `DataContext`

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:CTACallSubmitViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: Do they have the same DataContext? Are you explicitly setting the DataContext of CTACallSubmit somewhere?

Comment: Updated.  Based on your question I assume I need to explicitly say where nocustomer lives.  In this case, it would be the datacontext of the window that I bind to pass the data to the property of the usercontrol (visibility).

Comment: When you explicitly set a UserControl's DataContext to a CTACallSubmitViewModel instance, a Binding like `<views:CTACallSubmit Visibility="{Binding NoCustomer ...}"/>` expects the NoCustomer property in the CTACallSubmitViewModel instance. This is probably not what you want. You should usually not explicitly set a UserControl's DataContext, but use the one inherited from the parent control.

Comment: What happens if there is functionality (i.e., loading additional fields from a drop down box) that are specific to the user control but not specific to the parent control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following creates a new instance of `CTACallSubmitViewModel` and sets the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` to this one.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:CTACallSubmitViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

This means that the binding to the `NoCustomer` property of the other view model won't work unless you specify a source of the binding:

```
<views:CTACallSubmit x:Name="CallSubmit" 
        Visibility="{Binding DataContext.NoCustomer, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, 
        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Setting the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` like this is usually a bad idea as it breaks the inheritance of the parent's `DataContext`.

Comment: What would be the proper way of setting the datacontext for the usercontrol?

Comment: The proper way would be to let it inherit the DataContext from the parent window, just like the ContenControl does.

Comment: Yeah I planned to upvote but wanted to check some other things out.  I get an error saying that relativesource is not in find ancestor mode.  I assume I need to search for a type?  Also what throws me off is the content control just swaps datatemplates to other usercontrols that are bound the exact same way.  I would have assumed it would have also broke it.

Comment: Getting a xaml error that says: "RelativeSource is not in find ancestor mode"

Comment: Did you really copy my sample markup? It compiles just fine in a WPF application. Did you try to build?

Comment: Looks like I had to run clean on the solution.  Build was fine.  Just pesky xaml editor.